# Style sheet file custom.css.scss is not beign loaded in my rails application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to follow the tutorial my micheal harlt and have run into a small problem.It seems like my boot strap is not been imported correctly.Changes I made in custom.css.scss is not been reflected.

```
Custom.css.scss 

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
resize: vertical;
}

.center {
text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


Application.css.scss

/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css
    .
    .
    .

  *= require_self
  *= require_tree .
  */

  Gem file.

  source 'https://rubygems.org'

 gem 'rails', '3.2.16'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'




# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do    
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'

end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'


  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'.
```

When I try to access my home page it is still looking as a normal HTML page.
Is any thing missing here ??

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` and restart `web server`?

Comment: yes ! I did both the things.

Comment: Are you using rails 3.2?  Check this out https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#user-content-rails-32x

Comment: Yes I am using rails 3.2.16 and I have changed the version of my gem file bootstrap-sass to 3.1.1.0 ( as mentioned in the link) did bundle install and restarted the server.But the problem still persists.

Comment: I've never used it in rails 3.2. But this might could help you through https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/3.1-stable

Comment: I 'have added all the gem files required for rails 3.2 as mentioned in the link.When I am running "bundle install" it is showing error as : You have requested sprockets = 2.2.2.backport2.The bundle currently has sprockets locked at 2.12.3.
Try running `bundle update sprockets. When I am running "bundle update sprockets" it is showing that "Could not find gem 'sprockets (= 2.2.2.backport2) ruby' in the gems available on this machine." How to resolve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going down to:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.0'
```

Then run `bundle install`

The latest version of bootstrap-sass compatible with Rails 3.2 is v3.1.1.0. That might be the problem. 
[More in Bootstrap-sass page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)